# Prevent program from using ClipCursor?

Tags: winapi, cursor, mouse

An old game (Pod) is kept alive with a glide wrapper and thus can now be run in custom resolutions larger than the native game resolution which was 640x480.
However, due to problems with the glide wrappers, if the game is run at 1920x1080 for example, the cursor is only allowed to move in a 0, 0, 640, 480 rectangle; obviously the WinAPI ClipCursor function has been used by the original developers for this.
This is pretty nasty because you can't act with the game menu mouse-wise in a useful way since not all buttons can be reached.

Is it possible to disable ClipCursor() functionality globally? Do I have to inject a DLL (I didn't do this completely before) or would it just be enough to let a C# app run in the background, watching for the game process and setting ClipCursor() to the real screen area after the process has been started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seriously doubt it's calling ClipCursor() more than once. Try writing a small program to call ClipCursor() and set it back to the size of your desktop. Run that program after your game is started.

*edit*
Depending on your skill level, you could also try using ollydbg to step through the program and find where it's calling the ClipCursor() API, and insert a jump to skip over it.